# Copy is not working in grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
copy: {
              files: [
                {expand: true,cwd:"js/" ,src: ['libs/*'], dest: '../test/js/libs/'},
                {expand: true,cwd:"js/" , src: ['models/*'], dest: '../test/js/models/'}

              ]
        }
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
grunt.registerTask("testcopy",["copy"] );
);
```

I am learning grunt and I am facing below issue while copying . 
`Warning: undefined is not a function Use --force to continue.` 
and file not copied from src to destination

Comment: on which line in the above code the error happens ?

Comment: its not providing any line number . Just a message Warning: undefined is not a function Use --force to continue.

Comment: there is an `);` instead of `};` Is it a mistake in your code or on stack overflow?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the solution to your problem. But for things like copy or delete i always use the cli-commands directly with: https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell

Answer (score 0):

`grunt-contrib-copy` is a multi-target task, which means you have to give a "name" (called a target) to each of its configurations - that way you can define and call multiple copy operations (see http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets).

You do that by inserting names between "copy" and its parameters. Below is an example where I called the target "main":

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    copy: {
      main: {
        files: [
          {expand: true,cwd:"js/" ,src: ['libs/*'], dest: '../test/js/libs/'},
          {expand: true,cwd:"js/" , src: ['models/*'], dest: '../test/js/models/'}
        ]
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
  grunt.registerTask("testcopy",["copy:main"] );
};
```